Implement multiple-cucumber-html-reporter with webdriverIO & appium
Currently i am developing a mobile automation project in WebdriverIO & appium, as per requirement i have to integrate 'multiple-cucumber-html-reporter' this reporting system in that.
Any idea how to do this? or is it supporting in webdriverIO?
Also need to capture screenshot for failing tests.
I have tried to install 'multiple-cucumber-html-reporter' this package but its saying not supporting on latest webdriverIO version,
any idea how to customize it,
any help will be appreciable
